# Android. Repository with global lifecycle

Tags: android, repository, singleton, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle

I have a repository where a chain of network requests is calling. The repository is accessed from the interactor. And interactor is accessed from  viewModel. The view model is attached to activity `A`. If I go to activity `B`, which has its own viewModel, then the request chain in the repository of activity `A` does not complete its execution.

Is it possible to make a repository whose life cycle will be equal to the life cycle of the application. I need all requests to complete even if I go to a new activity.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [Coroutines guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#create-coroutines-data-layer) on developer.android.com

```
class ArticlesRepository(
    private val articlesDataSource: ArticlesDataSource,
    private val externalScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
) {
    // As we want to complete bookmarking the article even if the user moves
    // away from the screen, the work is done creating a new coroutine
    // from an external scope
    suspend fun bookmarkArticle(article: Article) {
        externalScope.launch(defaultDispatcher) {
            articlesDataSource.bookmarkArticle(article)
        }
            .join() // Wait for the coroutine to complete
    }
}
```

Here `externalScope` is defined like this (for a scope with application lifetime):

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
  // No need to cancel this scope as it'll be torn down with the process
  val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + otherConfig)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a singleton Repository class, then access its instance anywhere you want.

```
object Repository {
    val instance: Repository
        get() {
            return this
        }
}
```

You can create create its object in ViewModel for A and create object in ViewModel for B.
Both will have same instance for Repository class, so in this way you can achieve what you need.